# Python BeautifulSoup - Find specific <li> in nested <div> & <ul>

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to extract "HORROR" from the following HTML:

```
<div class="synopsis-section">
    <div class="movie-add-info left">
        <ul>
            <li>DIRECTOR : Matthew Vaughn</li>
            <li>ACTORS : </li>
            <li>DURATIONS : 107 Minutes</li>
            <li>CENSOR RATING : 17+</li>
            <li>GENRE : HORROR</li>
            <li>LANGUAGE : BAHASA INDONESIA</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
```

I tried it this way:

```
    >> response = get(url)
    >> html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    >> containers = html_soup.find('div', class_='movie-add-info left')
    >> containers.li
```

Output :
<'li'>DIRECTOR : Matthew Vaughn<'/li'>

There's no specific 'li' for 'HORROR';
Can anyone help me to just get "HORROR" out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(my_html, 'lxml')

result = soup.find('div', {'class': 'movie-add-info left'}).find('ul').findChildren(text=re.compile(r'GENRE'))

print(result[0])
```

output:

```
GENRE : HORROR
```

If you only want `'HORROR'`, just split it:

```
print(result[0].split()[2])
```

Comment: I suspect (for future use) OP might want to check `if 'GENRE' in x.text` and grab the correct genre (in this case horror) for further use

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector to get the desired output without the help of regex.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

root = fromstring(my_html)
genre = root.cssselect(".movie-add-info li:contains('GENRE')")[0].text
print(genre.split(":")[1].strip())
```

Result:

```
HORROR
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pure python

```
pattern = "<li>GENRE : "

with open("file.html") as file:
    for line in file:
        if pattern in line:
            print(line.replace(pattern, "").replace("</li>", "").strip())
```

> output:
>
> HORROR